# Smarty 3.1.1 kills newlines

Tags: php, html, templates, smarty, newline

I have this Smarty template.

```
<p>
    {foreach from=$fields item=field};{$field.dbName};{/foreach}
</p>
```

But instead of

```
<p>
    ;test1;;test2;
</p>
```

it prints me the following:

```
<p>
    ;test1;;test2;</p>
```

But why?

The `$smarty->compile_dir` file is correct. But the `$smarty->display()` function deletes my newlines. This is not what I want! I want a 1:1 output of my template.

I don't want a space char at the end of the `foreach` line. I don't want a 2nd newline after the `foreach` line.

Is there a config to turn this "feature" off?

Br

Comment: No there is not. It's "default PHP" behavior. If you need that line break, you'll have make it clear: `{/foreach}\n\n</p>`.

Comment: @rodneyrehm Default PHP behavior? No. When I use `print "<p>\ntest\n</p>";` it also works. But only with Smarty it doesn't work.

Comment: `<p>\n<?php … ?>\n</p>` and you'll see what I mean…

Comment: @rodneyrehm Yes, I see. You are right. Hm, that's not a Smarty problem. That's a PHP problem. Damn.

Comment: The problem is that Smarty replaces a `{$t}` with a `<?php echo $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['t']->value;?>`. Is it possible (maybe by config?) that Smarty take the content from the variable instead of printing the variable content with `<?php?>`.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to cover all scenarios, what if you do this:

```
<p>
  {foreach ...}
     ...
  {/foreach}
</p>
```

And you do NOT want the extra newlines created? Also in PHP:

```
<p>
  <?php foreach(...): ?> ... <?php endforeach(); ?>
</p>
```

You will still get the newline eaten after the last PHP code block.

That said, there will be a feature in Smarty 3.2 that cover eating newlines before and after smarty tags. Something like {-foo} will eat newlines before the tag, and {foo-} will eat newlines after the tag.